# Excel C# getting sum of a row dynamically

Tags: c#, excel, sum

My question is as follows: 
If i have a column with a static start point lets say A3, and a dynamic end point, lets say A827, or any other number, what would be the correct way to get the sum of this column?

What I thought of was as follows :

```
xl.Range sumcell;
            sumcell = xlNewSheet.Cells[xlNewSheet.Rows.Count, 1].End(xl.XlDirection.xlUp).Offset[1,0];
            sumcell.Formula = xl.WorksheetFunction.Sum(xlNewSheet.Range["A3"], xlNewSheet.Range["A3"].End(xl.XlDirection.xlDown));
```

The second idea I had was as follows :

```
xl.Range sumStart = xlApp.get_Range("A3");
            xl.Range sumEnd = xlNewSheet.Cells[xlNewSheet.Rows.Count, 1].End(xl.XlDirection.xlUp);
            xl.Range totalCell = sumEnd.Offset[1, 0];
totalCell.Formula = "=SUM(" + sumStart + ":" + sumEnd + ")";
```

Can anyone tell me if I'm on the right track or if i need to rethink the idea ?
Any sort of help would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've mannaged to solve it on my own. In case somebody might ever need/find this helpful, here it is :

```
sumEnd = xlNewSheet.Cells[xlNewSheet.Rows.Count, 1].End(xl.XlDirection.xlUp);
        xl.Range totalCell = xlNewSheet.Cells[xlNewSheet.Rows.Count, 1].End(xl.XlDirection.xlUp).Offset[1, 0];

        totalCell.Formula =xlApp.WorksheetFunction.Sum(xlNewSheet.Range[xlNewSheet.Range["A3"], sumEnd]);
```

Turns out i don't need to create an excel range with where it starts !